# Android: MediaPlayer onPrepared is not being called

Tags: android, media-player, prepare

As title says, the onPrepared() overridden method is not being called.

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
      if (mp.equals(mediaPlayer)) isReady_mediaPlayer = true;

      Log.e("I", "Media player has been loaded to memory !");
   }
});

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_sound_mp3);
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because you are creating a new `MediaPlayer` object. This one does not have any `onPreparededListener` set on it.

Here you create and assign a `MediaPlayer` object:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Next you set an `onPreparedListener` on it.

But then you create and assign a new one! This assignment overrides your previous lines.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_sound_mp3);
```

This one has no `onPreparedListener` set on it.

To fix, don't use the `create` method, use `setDataSource` instead

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.my_sound_mp3);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
       if (mp.equals(mediaPlayer)) isReady_mediaPlayer = true;
       Log.e("I", "Media player has been loaded to memory !");
    }
});
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Comment: What if I pass the MediaPlayer.create(... first instead of the MediPlayer() constructor?

Comment: Think of `MediaPlayer.create()` as a utility method that creates a new Mediaplayer object, sets the datasource, then calls prepare. All in one go. There is no way to short-circuit that. Juse use `setDataSource`, I have included it above. You can even see it in the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.create%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.net.Uri%2Candroid.view.SurfaceHolder%29

Comment: I know this is old but I am using the code from this post and inside the onPrepared() I try mediaPlayer.start() and file does not play?